# How to write first Map-Reduce Job programe for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am a very new to hadoop and trying to learn Hadoop, I found many reference and learned lot of things about hadoop architecture from different resources..

I have setup the Single Cluster setup in my machine and following the book "Hadoop_ The Definitive Guide, 3rd Edition"..

In 2nd chapter they telling about one example from "National Climatic Data Center"..

But I want to know which Jar file should I include in my project and how to start writing my first map-reduce job programe..

Thanks in Advance,
Sombir

Answer (score 0):

In `MR1`, the required jars for a basic job are the following :

- hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar
- commons-logging-api-x.x.x.jar
  It's not a direct dependency but absence causes problem on running the jar

Both these jars are available at the Hadoop installation directory, so pick them from there(to eliminate  version issue). As you try more features, additional jars will be needed. For example, `commons-cli-x.x.jar` has to be added to use `GenericOptionParser`.

Not very much sure about `Yarn`, but following jars are must :

- hadoop-common.jar
- hadoop-auth.jar

I'll update this list as soon be able to confirm.

Now to write the job, I think WordCount example(aka the `Hello World` of MR) is the best point to start. If you're comfortable with it, start the 'National Climatic Data Center' thing yourself. For any assistance, we can guide. Or better add the problem to this post to get the initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following 2 steps you might want to perform.

1. Install/setup hadoop [click here](http://www.howtoinstallhadoopinubuntu.blogspot.in/) for details
2. run a sample word count example in hadoop. [click here](http://www.hadoopforum.org/home.php?action=viewArticle&articleId=14) for details.